# javascript not working in all browsers

Tags: javascript, button, input

I have looked all over the place and have tried all kind of scripts but i keep running into the same problem.

I am trying to disable or hide a submit button until a checkbox is checked.

The problem I am having is that nothing is working in IE10 unless I have the compatibility turned on, and they do not work in FF 20.0.1 most of the time.

Here is what I have tried so far.

---

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="yes" onclick="agreed.disabled = !this.checked" />Do you Agree? &nbsp;
    <input type="submit" name="agreed" id="agreed" value="{L_AGREE}" class="button1" disabled="disabled" />
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkSubmit(ele, id) {
    x = document.getElementById(id);
    if (ele.checked == true) x.disabled = false;
    else x.disabled = true;
}
</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" onclick="checkSubmit(this, 'agreed')" value="y" />Do you Agree? &nbsp;
<input type="submit" name="agreed" id="agreed" value="{L_AGREE}" class="button1" disabled="disabled" />
```

---

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$("#terms").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#agreed').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#agreed').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});

});//]]>  

</script>

            <input type="checkbox" class="required" id="terms"/>Do you Agree? &nbsp;
            <input type="submit" name="agreed" id="agreed" value="{L_AGREE}" class="button1" disabled="disabled" />
```

---

I have tried many many other ways to do it but still running into problems with either IE10 or FF.

What I need is help with getting something to work in all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is more likely to work some browsers and not others depending on if they put elements on the `window` or `document` objects via their ID.

To fix it, use `document.getElementById()`.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="yes" onclick="document.getElementById('agreed').disabled = !this.checked" />Do you Agree? &nbsp;
<input type="submit" name="agreed" id="agreed" value="{L_AGREE}" class="button1" disabled="disabled" />
```

---

The second one should work in any browser as long as the function is global, though you can shorten it.

```
function checkSubmit(ele, id) {
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = !ele.checked;
}
```

Comment: @gdoron: Same to you! :-) Not sure how long I'll be back, but I did miss being cranky at the lazy people.

Comment: What do you mean by global?

Comment: @MikeFipps: It needs to be a global variable/function. In your code in the question, it is global because it's not nested inside another function. But if you do put your function inside another, that nests it in a local variable scope, and so it won't be reachable by the inline `onclick` handler.

Comment: @ am not i am: Thank you for explaining that. I know somethings in JavaScript but something are way over my head and I am learning as I go.